# regex to not allow special characters failing in python

Tags: python, regex

strings like this are fine

chris test 1

christest1

these are not

chris ^&*^&*^%^(

^%^&%^&$*(%christest1

chris test 1 %^&%(^*)&)(*&

basically it should just be letters numbers and spaces.

however my code is still validating strings with special characters.

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = ContentCreatorCreatorDisplayNameUniqueValidCheckSerializer(data=request.data)
        if data.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            data = data.validated_data
            # check if the name is valid
            # only letters numbers and spaces
            pattern = re.compile('([a-zA-Z0-9\s])+')
            print(data['name'])
            if pattern.match(data['name']):
                print('it validated the pattern')
```

the important regex lines being:

```
pattern = re.compile('([a-zA-Z0-9\s])+')
                print(data['name'])
                if pattern.match(data['name']):
```

when I do a check on regExr.com

the code works against test input as shown in the image.

Is there something I am missing with python? Is my regex still off?

[regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aphbI.png)

Comment: Why not instead write a regex that looks for a *single* character that is *not* in that character class? You know [you can invert character classes](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#matching-characters), right? Actually that whole page is a useful resource.

Comment: As an aside, no need to recompile the regex each time. If you do re.match('([a-zA-Z0-9\s])+', data['name'])`, `re` will compile it the first time but then cache and use the cached value from then on.

Comment: It helps to write a script that focuses just on your problem. if the problem is that `re.match('([a-zA-Z0-9\s])+', 'chris ^&^&^%^(')` doesn't reject that string, then that's your question right there. Just remove everything unrelated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `re.match` method only makes sure that the match starts from the beginning of a given string. You still have to anchor the end of the string with a `$` to ensure the pattern covers the entire string:

```
pattern = re.compile('[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+$')
```